# A rather simple rebus

Tags: rebus

I feel like this may be already out there somewhere, but I really did think this up on my own. What does this rebus puzzle mean?

> GO GO GO GO GO GO GO GO

That's really it! No additional hints exist in any of the content not in block quotes.

Hint:

> The answer has 5 words.

Comment: If you add or remove a GO, would the answer still remain the same?

Comment: No, if I did that the puzzle would be meaningless. It needs to have this many! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Could it be:

> It takes two to tango?

Rather cryptically, the rebus puzzle depicts:

> It takes two (more go) to (get) ten go.

Comment: Yes! Well done you, and I hope the solution is not an unreasonable one. :)

Comment: I don't think the solution is unreasonable. The "cryptically" just refers to the fact that it adds one more level to most other answers, that take the "eight go" at face value.

Answer (score 10):

I guess the answer you're after is:

> to forego

because indeed

> 2 * GO GO GO GO = two (four GO)

Comment: Afraid not, I am confident my answer is a better fit. Really great try, though!

Answer (score 7):

Any Chance it'd be:

> Go Wait in a line

as in

> Go * 8 in a line

Comment: This sounds right to me (but I'd suggest the small change of "Go wait in line", i.e. without the 'a', as more idiomatic).

Comment: This is actually a pretty good attempt, and I did not foresee this. Not the answer I had in mind though, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Is it

> Forgot to go

Implying

> 4 GO x 2 GO = 8 GO (Four-go-two-go) = forgot to go

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a bit of a stretch, but

> Great Times

Because

> *'"GO" eight times'* if said quickly, would sound something like 'go-wait times'*. For someone with a [rhotacism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhotacism_(speech_impediment)), like Elmer Fudd, this would be pronounced almost identical to *'great times'*.

Comment: Creative, but not quite. :)

Answer (score 2):

Probably

> **GO**es in line...
>
> with?

As in:

> Rhymes with.

Answer (score 1):

I feel,

(EDITED ANSWER):

> Goes online (that is LIVE!)

based on pronounciation mainly

> 8 GOs arranged in a line

a common phrase of usage.

Comment: Nice try, but no. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is

> Everything is a go

meaning

> All preparations are complete